# How to filter a loop through local storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to add links to my navbar for searches that users have made, as well as if the user favorites the link. What I'm currently trying to achieve is that if, if the "past searched" section already contains the current search, don't add the current search to avoid duplicates. I am using `localStorage` to store this data with a stringified array (`alreadySearched`) and check if this array includes the current search; my problem **is that the function always returns false.** The same thing happens for the favorites dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```js
// primary movie information (API #1)
var getMovie = function(title) {
  $("#result").addClass("hidden")
  $("#main").removeClass("hidden");
  $("#search-form").trigger("reset");
  //format the OMDB api url 
  var apiUrl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${title}&plot=full&apikey=836f8b0`
  //make a request to the url 
  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
      // request was successful 
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(function(movieData) {
          // console.log(movieData)
          var movieTitle = movieData.Title
          getMovieId(movieTitle);
          getSoundTrack(movieTitle);
          getTrailer(movieTitle);
          var movieObj = {
            title: movieTitle,
          }
          var pastSearches = loadPastSearches();
          var alreadySearched = false
          if (pastSearches) {
            pastSearches.forEach(s => {
              if (s.title === movieTitle) {
                alreadySearched = true;
              }
            })
          }
          if (!alreadySearched) {
            for (var item of pastSearches) {
              let searchEl = document.createElement("a")
              let pastSearchTitle = item.title
              $(searchEl).text(pastSearchTitle)
              $(searchEl).addClass("past-search-item");
              $("#past-search-dropdown").append(searchEl)
              $(searchEl).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let title = pastSearchTitle
                getMovie(title)
                getQuotes(title)
              });
            }
          }
          saveSearch(movieObj)
          showMovie(movieData);
        });
      } else {
        alert("Error: title not found!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert("Unable to connect to CineXScore app");
      console.log(error)
    });
};


// save past search
var saveSearch = function(movieObj) {
  var pastSearches = loadPastSearches();
  pastSearches.push(movieObj);
  localStorage.setItem("movieObjects", JSON.stringify(pastSearches))
}
loadPastSearches = function() {
  var pastSearches = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movieObjects"));
  if (!pastSearches || !Array.isArray(pastSearches)) {
    var pastSearches = []
  }
  return pastSearches;
}
// dropdown favorite soundtrack buttons 
var saveTrack = function(trackObj) {
  var faveTracks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("trackObjects"));
  if (!faveTracks || !Array.isArray(faveTracks)) {
    var faveTracks = []
  }
  var alreadySearched = false
  if (faveTracks) {
    faveTracks.forEach(t => {
      if (t.name === trackObj.name) {
        alreadySearched = true;
      }
    })
  }
  if (!alreadySearched) {
    let trackEl = document.createElement("a")
    $(trackEl).addClass("fave-track");
    $(trackEl).text(trackObj.name);
    $(trackEl).attr("href", trackObj.url);
    $(trackEl).attr("target", "_blank")
    $("#favorite-tracks-dropdown").append(trackEl)
  }
  faveTracks.push(trackObj);
  localStorage.setItem("trackObjects", JSON.stringify(faveTracks))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Navigation Menu -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <a id="logo" class="navbar-brand">CineXScore</a>
  <div class="dropdown navbar-brand">Past Searches
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div id="past-search-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a id="clear-searches">Clear</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown navbar-brand">Favorite Tracks
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div id="favorite-tracks-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a id="clear-favorites">Clear</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work?" What was the expected result, and what did you receive instead?

Comment: it re-adds all the elements from local storage regardless of if the title is already been searched for (so if you search for "titanic" twice then it will be in the dropdown list twice)

Comment: Right now I don't have a definite solution, but there are some issues with the code I'd like to point out. First, `loadPastSearches` should use a declarator (e.g. `var`) and put it in front of your other functions, or simply declare it with `function loadPastSearches() {...}`. Secondly, whenever you have an if statement to check if the local storage item is an array, you are adding a `var` to the variable you want to change, thus declaring a new variable that does who-knows-what. Finally, `console.log` is your friend (for debugging).

Comment: thank you for that help!  If I changed the "var" to let like this, would that solve one of the issues you mentioned?                                                                          ` var loadPastSearches = function() {
  let pastSearches = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movieObjects"));
  if (!pastSearches || !Array.isArray(pastSearches)) {
    pastSearches = []
  }
  return pastSearches;
}`

Comment: No, what I mean is that a declarator (i.e. `var`, `let`, or `const`) will "re-declare" a variable, which certainly won't do what you wish. You should remove it in the areas I described, as you have already declared the variable already, so you can actually mutate the variable.

Comment: okay noted! thanks!

Comment: thank you for the clarification I believe I solved the problem using `var loadPastSearches = function() {
  var pastSearches = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movieObjects"));
  if (!pastSearches || !Array.isArray(pastSearches)) return []
  else return pastSearches;
}`

Comment: Great. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple implementation that I think might help you.

```
async function fetchMovie(movieTitle) {
  const apiUrl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${movieTitle}&plot=full&apikey=836f8b0`;

  let res = await fetch(apiUrl);
  res = await res.json();

  const title = res.Title;
  saveSearch(title); //   Should only pass the string:title
}

fetchMovie('spiderman');

function saveSearch(title) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('movies')) localStorage.setItem('movies', ''); //   Initialize the localStorage

  //   e.g: (In localStorage)
  //   Avenger,Spiderman,The Antman etc..
  //   return this string & convert into an array

  let movies = localStorage
    .getItem('movies')
    .split(',')
    .filter((n) => n);

  //   Check if the title is already exists
  if (!movies.includes(title)) {
    movies.push(title);
  }

  //   Also store in localStorage as a string seperated by commas (,)
  movies = movies.join(',');

  localStorage.setItem('movies', movies);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will try that out!